# Аргументы в функции Replace

Tags: c#, .net

Возможно ли в функции Replace в качестве одно из аргумента использовать регулярное выражение?
Если да, то какой синтаксис?

Comment: используйте `Regex.Replace` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: [String.Replace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8), [StringBuilder.Replace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.replace?view=netframework-4.8), [Regex.Replace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.8)? О чём именно речь?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете подключить `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

И тогда использовать `Regex.Replace(...)`
Например:

```
string inputText = "Text 123 text 123";
string pattern = "\\d+";
string outputText = Regex.Replace(inputText, pattern , "numbers");
// outputText  => "Text numbers text numbers"
```

[Regex.Replace Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.8)